# Determine direction of bias with measurement error

Tags: least-squares, bias, measurement-error, endogeneity

We want to estimate the following population model:

$$y_i=\beta x_i+\epsilon_i$$

with $E[y_i]=E[x_i]=$ and $E[x_i\epsilon_i]=0$. We cannot observe $x_i$ directly, but we observe two variables $x_i^a$ and $x_i^b$ that are related to $x_i$ in the following manner:

$$x_i^a=\alpha x_i+\upsilon_i^a$$
$$x_i^b= x_i+\upsilon_i^b$$

with $\alpha\ne0$ unknown, $\upsilon_i^a$ and $\upsilon_i^b$ are classical measurement errors with $E[\upsilon_i^a]=E[\upsilon_i^a]=E[\upsilon_i^a\upsilon_i^b]=0$.

Now, combining the original model with the form of $x_i^a$ and rearranging we have the model:

$$y_i=\gamma x_i^a+u_i$$

where $u_i=\epsilon_i-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\upsilon_i^a$ and $\gamma=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$. The latter model of $y_i$ exhibits endogeneity, and I want to know the direction of the bias of estimating $\gamma$ with OLS, then I make use of the following form of OLS estimate $\hat\gamma$:

$$\begin{align} \hat\gamma & =\gamma+({(x^a)}'x^a)^{-1}(x^a)'u \\ & = \gamma+\frac{\sum_{i}x_i^au_i}{\sum_{i}(x_i^a)^2}. \end{align}$$

I tried taking conditional expectation on $x^a$ but I do not get something that looks useful for determining the direction of the bias. Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which is the quantity you ultimately care about in this model? I initially assumed it was $\beta$ (as it describes the relationship between $x$ and $y$ in the original model), but later in the question you focus on $\gamma$.

Comment: The situation where we care about $\beta$ but can't estimate it directly with OLS because we observe $x$ with measurement error is known as an errors-in-variables model. You typically need to make some additional assumptions to make sure the model is identifiable.